# Xcode relative file path

Tags: xcode

There is a behavior in Xcode that is bugging me for quite a while now:

When I create a new file, and I want this file to be inside a folder, I go to `File` > `New` > `File` > New swift file.

Then I create a new folder for the file, lets say Scene1 and, add the file there:

[image]

However, in Xcode, the current relative file path is the root of the project:

[image]

So, I try moving the file to the right location and creating a group for it, but (probably because the folder already exists), I got the error:

> Could not rename “New Group” to “Scene1”.

Then I have to manually drag the folder from Finder to Xcode, mark `Create Groups` and `Copy items if needed` every time I need a new file.

What is the best way to create files in Xcode without this path mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "folder". There are only *groups*. If you want this file to be in a group, make the group, go into it, and make the file. Use groups in Xcode to keep things organized in Xcode. This has nothing to do with folders on disk; you should not make folders on disk, you should not even look inside your project folder. Use Xcode to manage your project.

If you want the group to correspond to a folder on disk too, fine, then let Xcode take care of that too: make a folder-linked group (your yellow *templateTest* is a folder-linked group).

But do not do what you are doing, i.e. ask Xcode for a new file and then make a folder along the way. That just messes up Xcode.